# Running another .cs file within the main program.cs file

Tags: c#, console

I'm very new to programming in general so I'm sure this question is naive.

So, I wrote a simple magic eight ball program and I wanted to move onto an adventure game, but I thought it would be neat to include the eight ball program in the game, like making a console menu where you could select either game.

So, my problem is, I don't know how to put my eightball program in a file, and then run it from the main program file with something like

```
eightball();
```

And if this can be done simply, could I also use it in an if statement, like

```
if (response == 1)
{
eightball();
}
```

Thank you all for your help!

Also I'm sure I ran across the answer in my research, however I probably didn't understand it.

Comment: are these both console applications?

Comment: The .cs file is a container for classes, Your main program (console application) is one class in a file with Entry point Main(). Create eightball.cs file that contain the logic of eightball class and use it in console application. I advice reading tutorial in creating /instantiating class in c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a look at [classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9afc042.aspx).

You will probably want to create a new **class file** and then add your code something like this:

```
namespace MyApplication
{
    class EightBall
    {
        public static void eightball ()
        {
            // Add your code here
        }
    }
}
```

Call it from your `Main`-function like this:

```
if (response == 1)
{
    EightBall.eightball();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
namespace MyApplication
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new /*the name of your program*/());
        }
    }
}
```